# Implement file upload functionality using javascript

Tags: javascript, file

I have to implement file-upload functionality. I have already written the backend part which can accept either File object or and array-of-bytes. The challenge is, how to pass File object or an array-of-bytes to back end from front end. I am writing front end in javascript. Does javascript provide any such functionality to capture the object in File format? Please help.

Comment: User multipart as support in form you use and also FormData in javascript to store the file as bytes and sent it to your backend.

Comment: Might want to check out http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Answer (score 0):

So well in that case you can use AJAX for file uploading,
[*Might not work in few old browsers*]

Hers my code snippet I used for my project, it uploads a file on click of button once file is selected.

```
$( "#uploadImage" ).on('click',function()
    {

      try {

        var file = $('#file_upload').prop("files")[0]; //file_upload is form's id
        var name = file.name;
        var size = file.size;
        var type = file.type;

        if (type != 'image/png' && type != 'image/jpeg' )throw {"msg": 'Invalid image type'}

        if (size > 1024 * 1024 * 2 )throw {"msg": 'Invalid image size'}


        var formObj = new FormData($('form')[1]);

        $.ajax({
          url: "YOUR URL",
          data: formObj,
          processData: false,
          contentType: false,
          dataType:'json',
          type: 'POST',
          success: function(data){
            // Success code
          }
        }); 

      }catch (e) {
        console.log(e.msg);
      }

    });
```

Comment: I need to do it without using ajax.